# XPages - Creating a Picklst from a categorised Column

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a categorised Column  which is the first column of my view "groupView", how could i use or filter this column in my picklist that i would not get a value appearing more than once?

I have a view with a list of student and the student belong  to different group, some student belong to two or more group,when i create a new student account i need to assign it to one or more group, so i want to make a picklist that display the first column of the view "groupView" which would make me select the group name and assign it to the new account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in your picklist data source.
    @Unique(@DbColumn("","view",1))

Comment: those the code go to the filter by category name or filter by column name or would i use it as the file name?

Comment: When the view is categorized you don't need the @Unique

Comment: When ever i use the code '@Unique(@DbColumn("","groupView",1))' i get run error: com.ibm.xsp.FacesExceptionEx: Too many keys

Comment: i have been able to get the value it return a string, how can i get the UNiD. i use selDocID = viewCollection.getUniversalID(); but i got  Error calling method 'getUniversalID()' on an object of type 'String

Comment: I think you need to update your question and provide code. I am not aware of anything labled "picklists" in xpages

Comment: Simon, if you're selecting a category value, there isn't just one document associated with it. Why would you want the UNID of the other student document anyway?